# How to create straight line with same css gradient at both ends?

Tags: css, linear-gradients

How would I create the below image using only CSS?

I'm attempting to draw a line with a transparent gradient at either end - here's what I've tried which does not work:

```
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent, #8C8C8C),
                  -webkit-linear-gradient(right, transparent, #8C8C8C);
```

So at the left and right end of the line the gradient moves inwards.

[image]

Comment: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just use a single gradient like in the below snippet with the start and end as transparent.

**Explanation:**

- `transparent 0%` means the gradient starts with transparent color
- `#8C8C8C 15%` means that between 0% to 15% the gradient's color gradually changes from transparent to `#8C8C8C`.
- `#8C8C8C 85%` means that the gradient's color stays as `#8C8C8C` from 15% to 85%.
- `transparent 100%` means that the gradient's color would again change gradually from `#8C8C8C` to transparent between 85% - 100%.

The color stops create the illusion as though the gradient is proceeding inwards from either direction. Equal splits make the change look equal on either side.

```css
div {
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, #8C8C8C 15%, #8C8C8C 85%, transparent 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(left, transparent 0%, #8C8C8C 15%, #8C8C8C 85%, transparent 100%);
  height: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The various color stop values can help achieve that effect.

Stop the white at 10% and prolong a mix of transparent and gray(increasing) up to 50% and then a mix of gray and transparent(increasing) up to 100%.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 10%, gray 50%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Also, you can play around with the `%` values to get the exact gradient. For example, your image can be made as accurate as possible by increasing the stop points like below.

```css
.gradient {
  width: 600px;
  height: 1px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 10%, gray 20%, gray 90%, transparent 98%, transparent 100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gradient"></div>
```

Comment: Actually you could avoid a few of those stops. white 2% is not needed (because body is already white and transparent would still keep it white only), gray 50%, gray 80% are also not needed because the gray 20% and gray 90% will keep it gray for 20-90%.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right about both the parts, I was writing the code in terms of equal mixing of colors and forgot about that. Thanks for the *clutter cleanup*. :)